# ¿Por qué la Conversión de Fecha de mi Sistema genera valores diferente en Win10 y Win7?

Tags: c#, windows10, windows7

Soy muy nueva en la programación y tengo una situación que no logro resolver. Estoy trabajando en un sistema de **windows forms** con **C#**, usando el **framework 4.6.1.**

Explico un poco de como hago la conversión y espero de verdad alguien me pueda apoyar.

El valor de fecha que recibo es de tipo `string` algo asi "15-ene.2020", estoy definidiendo una variable de `CultureInfo` a través de la propiedad `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` y cuando estoy ejecutando el programa en la maquina donde trabajo la cual tiene **windows10** la conversión se realiza correctamente 15/01/2020 pero **cuando hago la publicación de este sistema y lo ejecuto en maquinas con** **windows7** las fechas se muestran diferentes.

Siguiendo el ejemplo la conversión ahora se muestra como 01/01/2015.

Me encuentro muy desorientada y no logro solucionarlo, si alguien tiene alguna sugerencia le agradecería me comparta un poquito de su experiencia.

En esta linea de código recibo el el `string` en `recibo.fecha` y procedo a agregarlo a un `datarow` para insertar en un `datatable`.

```
string fechDr = Convert.ToDateTime(recibo.fecha,culturita).ToShortDateString();
dr["FECHA"] = fechDr;
```

Comment: No es un problema de windows, si no de la cultura de cada pc.. problamente tengan la fecha definida de distinta forma.. deberias trabajar con cultura invariante dentro de tu sistema.

Comment: De hecho antes no estaba usando Cultura, acabo de probarlo pensando que me resolveria el problema pero no fue así. Ya me asegure que el formato de la fecha en las maquinas de win10 y win7 este definido igual pero siguen mostrando fechas distintas :/

Comment: Como definis la cultura?

Comment: CultureInfo culturita = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

Comment: CurrentCulture es la del sistema operativo, no la que vos queres ;)

Answer (score 2):

No utilizaria CultureInfo.CurrentCulture porque culture es seteada según la versión del sistema operativo en cuestión, intentaría castear la fecha directamente a un string con el formato que quiero, algo así:

```
recibo.fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Saludos!

Comment: Intente hacerlo como me sugeriste, tampoco funcionó.